# MIPS calculation on ARM processor

Tags: c, arm, cpu-usage

Following this post:

[How to calculate MIPS for an algorithm for ARM processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678771/how-to-calculate-mips-for-an-algorithm-for-arm-processor).

I have a follow up question ,  Suppose i have only one process in my system ( working bare-metal on cortex M4F) , this process takes around ~ 3 seconds , the CPU frequency is 168 MHZ and the Cortex M4F is 1.25 MIPS/MHZ ,which gives me  : 210 MIPS  , so this is 3 * 210 = 630 MIPS total for the 3 second run time , am i correct ?

But ! , who can guarantee that in this 3 seconds i consume all of the available MIPS provided by the CPU ? if this is not  then the 630 MIPS is somehow inaccurate .

What if i will measure my CPU usage through the whole run-time ( suppose i will get ~ %50 CPU usage) so the true MIPS value is 315 MIPS , am i correct ? what is most correct way to get MIPS estimate?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: MIPS is "million instructions ***PER SECOND***". So you better not multiply by 3 seconds if you want your results and dimensions to be correct.

Comment: Why Not? So how the calculation should go then ?

Comment: @userXXXX Why not? See my comment above. How? You stop at the 210MIPS part.

Comment: So what should i say to the costumer , if you want your application to run in 3 seconds you should provide me a CPU capable of performing at 210MIPS?

Comment: And the CPU Usage is not a factor ? *because i am pretty sure that i am not using %100 of my CPU )

Comment: Well, it is. If there are multiple processes using the same CPU, then you have to divide that by some factor.

Comment: with your cpu clocked at that speed, if your code is on flash then there are a number of clock cycles per instruction fetch the processor has to wait so among other things you have that bottleneck.  you might try copying your code under test to ram and running it from there.  Just because the arm claims 1.25 mips to mhz doesnt mean you will ALWAYS get that, that is just for benchmarks that are tuned to advertise such things and for bursts of code.  Real programs wont always need or get that performance for many reasons

Comment: to continue my previous comment, you could turn on the caches to avoid the flash bottleneck.   Also note that these are pipelined processors so even a simple infinite loop with nops might not show full mips performance unless you know what you are doing and craft that loop to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

You can use dhrystone to benchmark the DMIPS.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second